# How do I safely remove/deactivate these switches wall sconces and outlet?

Tags: electrical

We want to remove these wall sconces (there are two of them) and patch up the wall.  We may want to still use the switched outlet.

[image: sconce]
[image: wiring close up]
[image: back of sconce]
[image: inside sconce]

If I want to keep the switched outlet how should I re-wire?

If I also want to removed the switched outlet how should I rewire?

Is it safe to keep the junction box there and push all the wires into the wall and patch up? 
That seems like it could be dangerous bc someone might drill into the hole later and hit live wires!

Comment: Are you OK with having blank box covers where the sconces were?

Comment: Also, can you get us a photo of the innards of the switched outlet box?

Comment: You cannot "patch over" the junction boxes unless you remove the wires from the wall. You can put blank covers on them, but those blank covers need to remain exposed and accessible (they can be painted to match the wall, but mudding over them is a distinct no-no - unfortunately one that too many folks have just done in ignorance,,,

Comment: Personally, I would put wire nuts over the ends and put on a blank cover plate and hang a picture over it or just paint it, (someone later might *want* a sconce there), but is it allowed by code to disconnect the wires (hots and neutrals) at a junction box closer to the panel and then cover over the box and abandon the wires in the wall?

Comment: "No lighting in the room and only a switched outlet for user-supplied floor lamp" is a safety hazard, because real-world, people defeat it. They don't have a floor lamp. Or they do but they turn it off *at the lamp* to save 3 steps.  Or they don't like the receptacle location and put it elsewhere.  Turning on the light becomes a secret code only the occupant knows. **Upshot: when a first-responder shows up for an emergency call and flicks the switch, *no light*.** Builders like it because it's cheaper to install, so they lobbied for it.  Terrible design.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the sconces? Are they in the way of traffic or do you want to place some tall furniture where they are?

Comment: We don't like them or the placement. :(